# Should Brillouin zone be a continuous object rather than a discrete one in the thermodynamic limit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, definition

For example, just consider a 1D atom chain with $N$ sites and lattice constant $a=2\pi$, under periodic boundary conditions, the crystal momentum reads as $k=\frac{n}{N}\frac{2\pi}{a}=\frac{n}{N}$, with $n=0,1,2,...,N-1$. In the thermodynamic limit $N\rightarrow \infty$, there would be infinitely dense $k$ points within the region $[0,1)$, and the Brillouin zone(**BZ**) is defined as the *continuous* real number interval **BZ** $=\left [0,1  \right )$.

But $k=\frac{n}{N}$ is always a rational number, why not define **BZ** to be a *discrete* set as **BZ** $=\mathbb{Q}\bigcap \left [0,1  \right )$ ? where $\mathbb{Q}$ represents the set of all rational numbers.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Since functions of $k$ are not pathological, defining the Brillouin as continuous or discrete would not produce any physical difference.